# gzuncompress not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, flash

I'm trying to create a Wordpress site where I can place SWF files ready for QC, and I would like SWF header information displayed beside the banner.

I'm using [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1653-PHP-Parse-header-of-Flash-files-to-extract-metadata.html) PHP Class

EDIT: (Code can also be found [here](http://www.zend.com//code/codex.php?ozid=1382&single=1)).

It works fine out of the box and stand alone, however when I'm trying to using on a custom post type in wordpress, it gets to a call to gzuncompress and stops.

And I can't figure out why I can't use gzuncompress within wordpress.

```
DEBUG: Data values initialized
DEBUG: Opened http://localhost:8888/previewer/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/test.swf
DEBUG: Read MAGIC signature: CWS
DEBUG: Read VERSION: 9
DEBUG: Partial SIZE read: 177
DEBUG: Partial SIZE read: 2560
DEBUG: Partial SIZE read: 65536
DEBUG: Partial SIZE read: 0
DEBUG: Total SIZE: 68273
We need to uncompress this
This didn't uncompress
DEBUG: RECT field size: 0 bits
DEBUG: RECT binary value: (0)
DEBUG: RECT binary value: (0)
DEBUG: RECT binary value: (0)
DEBUG: RECT binary value: (0)
DEBUG: Frame rate: 0.0
DEBUG: Frames: 0
DEBUG: Finished processing http://localhost:8888/previewer/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/test.swf
```

Where as if I create a index.php with:

```
<?php

    require ("swfheader.class.edit.php") ;
    $header = "test.swf";

$swf = new swfheader(true) ;
    // Open the swf file...
    // Replace filename accordingly to your test environment...
    $swf->loadswf($header) ;
    // Show data as a block... you can also access data within the object
    $swf->show() ;
?>
```

My output is the following:

```
DEBUG: Data values initialized
DEBUG: Opened test.swf
DEBUG: Read MAGIC signature: CWS
DEBUG: Read VERSION: 9
DEBUG: Partial SIZE read: 164
DEBUG: Partial SIZE read: 3840
DEBUG: Partial SIZE read: 65536
DEBUG: Partial SIZE read: 0
DEBUG: Total SIZE: 69540
We need to uncompress this
Uncompressing....
DEBUG: RECT field size: 14 bits
DEBUG: RECT binary value: 00000000000000 (0)
DEBUG: RECT binary value: 01011101110000 (300)
DEBUG: RECT binary value: 00000000000000 (0)
DEBUG: RECT binary value: 01001110001000 (250)
DEBUG: Frame rate: 24.0
DEBUG: Frames: 1
DEBUG: Finished processing test.swf
```

The code seems to fall down when it gets to the gzuncompress.

---

From what I've managed to narrow down, is that I cannot use a URL with gzuncompress, so I need a way of working around this. :/

Comment: The class you linked to requires registration to view. If you have a problem with a third party library, it would be smart to contact the library author for support.

Comment: Does the code that does the decompressing need to create a temporary file? Perhaps the location of that temporary file is different when run within Wordpress?

Comment: @DCoder I've amended my post, because I did find a link on ZEND which has the class.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I don't think so. The code works fine stand alone, just breaks when I use in within wordpress.

Comment: Can you provide the SWF file that fails? Or does this fail for *any* SWF file?

Comment: @DCoder any SWF fails

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue, it seems that you cannot put a url in gzuncompress. I tested this by placing the swf in the root directory of the WP install and running the page.php and it worked. I then also tested a URL into my stand alone test.php and that didn't work.

Comment: [PHP documentation: using remote files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php). But in my opinion, doing things like that over HTTP is wrong when the file is available locally.

Comment: @DCoder I took your advice, I just removed the site url from the $swf_file location and passed that into the SWF header class and it worked fine! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a HTTP URL into gzuncompress would not work, as it doesn't allow remote files.

The result is that I took the $website_url and removed that from the $swf_file_location using str_replace and ran that through the swfheader.class.php

```
$website_url = "http://example.com/";
$swf_file = "http://example.com/test_file.swf";

$swf_test = str_replace($website_url, "", $swf_file);

$swf->loadswf($swf_test) ;

$swf->show();
```